# Why "select" works in MariaDB but doesn't work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
set @row_number = 0;
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
        id,
        tbl_user_id,
        title,
        description,
        length lengths,
        create_date,
        file_size,
        thumbnails,
        videos.itsOK,
        viewed
    FROM
        tbl_videos videos
    WHERE
        videos.tbl_user_id = 23
            AND videos.tbl_category_id = 265
        ORDER BY videos.create_date DESC
) AS paginateTbl
WHERE
    paginateTbl.num > 0
        && paginateTbl.num <= 9
```

mysql results:
[image: mysql results]

mariadb results:
[image]

Inner query work on both of them but main query work only in mariadb! What's the matter in mysql not working?

Versions used are mysql: **`5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`** and mariadb **`10.0.13-MariaDB-log`**.

The `CREATE TABLE` statements are identical (except for the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, number of rows):

MySQL result:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_videos;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_videos` (
    `id` INT (20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`title` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`description` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`tags` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`video_quality` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`dl_link1` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`dl_link2` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`dl_link3` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`viewed` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`viewed_duration` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`viewed_traffic` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`embed_code` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`sharing_code` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`replace_times` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`actual_link` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`tbl_user_id` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`tbl_category_id` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`tbl_player_id` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`itsOK` TINYINT (2) NOT NULL
    ,`length` INT (20) NOT NULL
    ,`create_date` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`modified_date` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`thumbnails` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci
    ,`serverId` VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`sizes` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`our_server_link` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`like` INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,`file_size` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL
    ,`islogo` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci
    ,`uuid` VARCHAR(64) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`output_type` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`video_file` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`video_setting` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`soft_hard` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`soft_hard_logo` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`vastTag` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci
    ,`extra_cat_id` INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,`all_terafic` BIGINT (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ,KEY `tbl_user_id`(`tbl_user_id`)
    ,KEY `tbl_category_id`(`tbl_category_id`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `tbl_videos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_users`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT `tbl_videos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_category_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_categories`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 4622 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_persian_ci
```

MariaDB result:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_videos;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_videos` (
    `id` INT (20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`title` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`description` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`tags` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`video_quality` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`dl_link1` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`dl_link2` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`dl_link3` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`viewed` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`viewed_duration` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`viewed_traffic` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`embed_code` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`sharing_code` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`replace_times` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`actual_link` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`tbl_user_id` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`tbl_category_id` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`tbl_player_id` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`itsOK` TINYINT (2) NOT NULL
    ,`length` INT (20) NOT NULL
    ,`create_date` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`modified_date` INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,`thumbnails` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci
    ,`serverId` VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`sizes` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`our_server_link` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`like` INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,`file_size` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL
    ,`islogo` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci
    ,`uuid` VARCHAR(64) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`output_type` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`video_file` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`video_setting` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`soft_hard` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL
    ,`soft_hard_logo` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL
    ,`vastTag` TEXT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci
    ,`extra_cat_id` INT (11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,`all_terafic` BIGINT (20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ,KEY `tbl_user_id`(`tbl_user_id`)
    ,KEY `tbl_category_id`(`tbl_category_id`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `tbl_videos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_users`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT `tbl_videos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_category_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_categories`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 9387 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_persian_ci
```

---

mysql results:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from FROM ...
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14  Using where
2   DERIVED     videos      index_merge tbl_user_id,tbl_category_id tbl_category_id,tbl_user_id 4,4 NULL    1   Using intersect(tbl_category_id,tbl_user_id); Using where; Using filesort
```

mariadb results:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from tbl_videos
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   Using where
2   DERIVED videos  index_merge tbl_user_id,tbl_category_id tbl_category_id,tbl_user_id 4,4 NULL    1   Using intersect(tbl_category_id,tbl_user_id); Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: mysql '5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'

Comment: mariadb '10.0.13-MariaDB-log'

Comment: From what I see, seems your queries both run fine. But the mysql table has rows without any data in them. Perhaps add (`AND length>0`) in the inner query to show results that have some useful data and check again.

Comment: Inner query work on both of them but main query work only in mariadb!

Comment: The query returns 9 rows in both mysql and mariadb. So it works fine. The different output is because you have different data in the 2 tables. When you say it dosn't work, what do you mean? If you have no valuable data in the table, the query can't magically show something.

Comment: when i remove "order by" in inner query it work on mysql!

Comment: Run this against MySQL:`select * from tbl_videos where id = 4174` What value is in the description column?

Comment: it return true data in both!

Comment: Can you add (image or text) what the above query (`select * from tbl_videos where id = 4174;`) returns for mysql? If it truly retturns different results than the other, it would be a bug in mysql 5.5.44

Comment: Yes, It's truly. I check later with mysql 5.6.

Comment: (unrelated)  The query would run faster with a _composite_ `INDEX(tbl_user_id, tbl_category_id)`.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output of `select * from tbl_videos where id = 4174;`

Comment: it return true data in both! but in main query not work!
It's mysql 5.5 bug. so I installed mysql 5.6 and main query works well.

Comment: Please share a result (as code or image, link here in the comments if you can't add in the question.) It would be much better to have something that proves this is a bug. If the query (above with `id=4174`) returns different data in the other columns, it would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's MySQL 5.5 bug which [reported to MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78355). so I installed mysql 5.6 and main query works well. same query with @@version in results.

```
set @row_number = 0;
SELECT 
    *, @@version mysql_version
FROM
    (SELECT 
        (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
        id,
        tbl_user_id,
        title,
        description,
        length lengths,
        create_date,
        file_size,
        thumbnails,
        videos.itsOK,
        viewed
    FROM
        tbl_videos videos
    WHERE
        videos.tbl_user_id = 9
            AND videos.tbl_category_id = 113
            AND length > 0
        ORDER BY videos.create_date ASC
) AS paginateTbl
WHERE
    paginateTbl.num > 0
        && paginateTbl.num <= 9
```

mysql 5.5 & mysql 5.6 main query results:
[image: mysql 5.5 bug - main query]
[image: mysql 5.6 - main qu]

Now I check a special id eg: 1103 in tbl_videos and both select works well.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    tbl_user_id,
    title,
    description,
    length lengths,
    create_date,
    file_size,
    thumbnails,
    itsOK,
    viewed,
    @@version mysql_version
FROM
    tbl_videos
WHERE
    id = 1103
```

mysql 5.5 & mysql 5.6 results:
[image: mysql 5.5 bug - tiny query]
[image: mysql 5.6 - tiny query]

Comment: Did you find which bug exactly it was (a link to mysql bugs) and when it was fixed?

Comment: There would be more upvotes coming your way if you could provide more specific details of the bug in this answer. It would help people know if the problem they are seeing is likely to be fixed the same way (or if they are unable to upgrade immediately could give them the clues needed to work around or otherwise mitigate the problem in the meantime)

Comment: Would you like to send the screen shot of mysql 5.5 and mysql 5.6 of retured data?

Comment: Nice. I think you should also make a bug request at the MySQL site. 5.5 is still a supported version and bugs like this should be fixed.